# How to execute sh script for files beginning with minus and including spaces?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, xargs

I am trying this:

```
ls | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs sh -- script.sh
```

for files:

- -test 23.txt
- test24.txt
- te st.txt

but after this, script.sh executed only for:

```
-test 23.txt
```

Comment: A file whose name is starting with minus can always be given as e.g. `./-test 23.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs`, by default, assumes that the command it is expanding can take multiple arguments. In your example, `xargs` would have executed

```
sh -- script.sh "-test 23.txt" "test24.txt" "te st.txt"
```

If your script only echoes its first argument, then you'll only see `-test 23.txt`

You can tell `xargs` to execute the command for every input by using the `-n1` flag.

In many cases, `xargs` is *not* what you want, even coupled with the `find` command (which has a useful `-exec` action). When it is what you want, you usually want to use the `-0` flag coupled with some flag on the other side of the pipe which delimits arguments with `NUL` characters instead of spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Better use a **glob** :

```
./script.sh *
```

No need to add *double quotes* like you try

If your script don't loop over the arguments, try this :

```
for i in *; do ./script.sh "$i"; done
```

Comment: If the script thinks an argument starting with "-" (like "-test 23.txt") is a flag rather than a filename, add this after the `do`: `[ "${i:0:1}" = "-" ] && i="./$i";`